# Proper way to play character cards?

Tags: citadels

I have a few questions below.

1) Do we play the character card to the center of the table (stacking on previous character)? or we place in front of us?

2) I also understand from the rules that the assassinated character suppose to act stupid upon their character is called. Question here is, at the end of the round, does the king have to verify who are the assassinated character is? or it's like poker where u can return the card without revealing yourself?

3) Can we purposely skip our character (act like it's assassinated to avoid tax collector)?

4) When the last character is called and someone still holding non-assassinated character, how should we deal with such situation?

Thanks for clearing my doubts :)

Comment: You should split this question up into multiple questions so they can be better answered.

Comment: While I agree that posters should generally stick to a single-question format, in this case the questions are all basically components of a single question, which is whether you can feign being assassinated or not.

Comment: @user30903 Question 1 is distinctly a different question from questions 2 through 4.

Comment: _When the last character is called and someone still holding non-assassinated character, how should we deal with such situation?_ Don't invite them to play with you anymore. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It doesn't matter, you are revealing the card to let everyone know it is now your turn.
2. I wouldn't say that the assassinated character plays stupid they just don't get a turn. And at the end of the round you know who everyone is so there is no reason whatsoever to try and hide it.
3. No you can't skip your turn your turn to avoid the negative effects of another character. That is just straight up cheating

> When the name of your character card is called, you must reveal your character card, place it face up in front of you, and take your turn.

4. If you found that someone cheated and did not play then depending on if they where the last one that was supposed to play or not you either make them play (if they where the last ones to play) and make any negative effects that they where trying to avoid happen (such as losing all their money) and if its still a problem them make them lose the game and start the next round with one less player.

Answer (score 3):

The [rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Citadels/support/citadels-rules-english.pdf) explicitly state [italics mine]:

> When the name of your character card is called, you *must* reveal your character card, place it face up in front of you, and take your turn.

If your character has been assassinated, you say nothing and do not acknowledge that you have been assassinated in any way. It will be obvious by the round's end, however, that you did not play a turn and that you were the assassinated character.

Using the most sensible interpretation of the above rules, it follows that it would be considered cheating to pretend that your character was assassinated when it in fact was not.

Since every character is called in numeric order, there shouldn't be any unplayed characters left in anyone's hands at the end of the round, except of course for the assassinated character.

Answer (score 1):

Good answers have been provided for your last three questions, but I feel there's more to be said about your first question. <s>There's no rule on where you place your cards, but</s> there are certainly reasons to keep the card in front of you instead of stacking it at the center of the table.

- If your character has an extra action in another character's turn (Witch, Thief, Tax Collector) the card in front of you can serve as a reminder of that action.
- If you're the King or Emperor, and the Queen is in play, your card can help in identifying whether or not the Queen gets her 3 gold bonus.
- If you're the Bishop, your card will identify to the Warlord that he can't target your districts with his ability.

You can do all these things without keeping the cards in front of you, but I find it a lot easier to just collect them at the end of the round.

Comment: As per my answer above, the official rules do say that your card is placed "face up in front of you." Does this really still leave any question as to whether the cards are stacked in a common pile? To me, that wording is unambiguous.

Comment: What you're saying is true, it's in the rules as well as in your answer. But I prefer intrinsic motivation over quoting the rules, so I felt there was more to be said about the first question.